# Calling a sub routine from within at half the current rate

Tags: .net, vb.net, stack-overflow, subroutine, timespan

I have a subroutine that is being called to the beat of a playing track to trigger DMX lighting. So the routine is not being called by a Timer event and the calls might increase or decrease with the tracks rhythm.
What I would like to be able to do is to call the same sub routine from within itself at twice the current frequency.
I am unable to change the sending call as this is being sent from equipment I have no control over.
My thoughts were perhaps get the time of the last 2 beats, divide that by 2 then call the same sub again. I would obviously have to prevent the division from happening more than once.

This is what I have come up with but I get
System.StackOverflowException was unhandled occurred in mscorlib.dll
  InnerException: Unable to evaluate expression.

on the line "If DateTime.Now + interval >= DateTime.Now Then"

```
 Private Sub do_pan_robo_colors()

    Dim ts As TimeSpan = Now.Subtract(last_beat_time)
    If Not ts.TotalSeconds > 10 Then 'prevent overflow 
        Dim time_between_beats As Double = ts.TotalMilliseconds
        Dim half_between_beats As Double = time_between_beats / 2
        Dim interval As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(half_between_beats)
        If DateTime.Now + interval >= DateTime.Now Then
            do_pan_robo_colors()
        End If
    End If
    last_beat_time = DateTime.Now

    'trigger DMX lamp

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured a solution

```
Private Sub do_pan_robo_colors(ByVal hardware_beat As Boolean)

    If hardware_beat = True Then
         Dim ts As TimeSpan = Now.Subtract(last_beat_time)
         If Not ts.TotalSeconds > 10 Then 'prevent overflow 
            Timer_half_beat.Interval = ts.TotalMilliseconds / 2
            Timer_half_beat.Start()
         End If
         last_beat_time = Now
    End If

    'Send DMX
```

and in a timer

```
Private Sub Timer_half_beat_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer_half_beat.Tick
    do_pan_robo_colors(False)
    Timer_half_beat.Stop()
End Sub
```